# vb.net find line that contain in a string

Tags: vb.net, contains, webresponse

If I can find line that contains word in a file

```
File.ReadAllLines(html).FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Contains("something"))
```

How can I find all lines that contains in a string 
for example I made an webresponse

```
    Dim rt As String = "http://www.somesaite.com"
    Dim wRequest As WebRequest
    Dim WResponse As WebResponse
    Dim SR As StreamReader
    wRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(rt)
    WResponse = wRequest.GetResponse
    SR = New StreamReader(WResponse.GetResponseStream)
    rt = SR.ReadToEnd
```

How to find lines that contains in `rt` ?

Comment: Either read line by line by using a loop and `SR.ReadLine()` or split the whole text into an array like this: `Dim arr() As String = SR.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine)`.

Comment: @VisualVincent you mean Split the  whole html code line by line to arry then use `For Each Str As String In arr
   
 If Str.Contains("something")` ?????

Comment: No, split it into an array and call `.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Contains("something"))` on that array. `File.ReadAllLines()` returns an array of string.

Comment: @VisualVincent can you pleas write it as an answer for me i only mange to get one line and i want more than one

Comment: Yep, give me a few minutes

Comment: A little change... Could you first show me what you get and how you get it? Becase I am uncertain what you get from the response.

Comment: @VisualVincent `Dim html As String = SR.ReadToEnd`  then ` Dim htmlarr() As String = html.Split(Environment.NewLine)` and `Dim find As String = htmlarr.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Contains("somethingl"))`

Comment: My answer works for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read all the text that the `StreamReader` gives you, and then you could split that by the `Environment.NewLine` character(s). Then you should just be able to use the lambda expression you first mentioned (as the `File.ReadAllLines()` method returns an array of strings).

```
Dim FoundLine As String = SR.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine).FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Contains("something"))
```